# DisplayPort over Thunderbolt 2 to DisplayPort over USB-C?

Tags: display

Is Thunderbolt 2 compatible with USB-C specifically with regards to video functionality with devices that support DisplayPort through the connectors?

Will a [Dell S2722QC](https://www.dell.com/en-au/shop/dell-s2722qc-27-4k-uhd-usb-c-monitor/apd/210-bccw/monitors-monitor-accessories) monitor's video functionality work with a [MBP 11,3](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.5-15-dual-graphics-mid-2014-retina-display-specs.html) using the USB-C & Thunderbolt 2 ports, and would [this style](https://www.amazon.com.au/Cable-Matters-USB-DisplayPort-Supporting/dp/B0777S15V2) of mini DisplayPort to USB-C cable work?

I've read this similar answer: [MBP Mini-DisplayPort to USB-C Monitor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392404/mbp-mini-displayport-to-usb-c-monitor) but from the monitor's [spec sheet](https://www.lg.com/au/it-monitors/lg-27MD5KA-B-black) I think that question was actually referring to a Thunderbolt 3 device.

Comment: not sure enough, so just a comment: it says *unidirectional* right in the title of the cable, which leads me to believe it won't work, since you want to go DP to USB-C. Why not get a DP to HDMI cable?

Comment: @X_841 that's a good point, I hadn't considered DP to HDMI. Would that restrict the display bandwidth at all? The specs on my machine list the built in HDMI port with a lower resolution + refresh rate compared to DP. I'm not super familiar with DP over X implementations - I was hoping the DP signal would be used in both TB2 & USB-C in this case, just with a different physical connector which would allow me to use the mini DP to USB-C cable.